# How to route correctly with a mixture of parent and child routes with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to play around with Reacter-Router, but running into issues when I start introducing some child routes, and getting them to then route back to the parent routes.

I've attached a CodeSandbox link below which contains the current code, if anyone can see where I'm going wrong?

What I'm trying to do is to have a set of parent and child routes, and allow routing from parent --> child & from child --> parent. You'll see in the example that the child routes do not work, but if you navigate straight to `higher_level_route`, it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-tdd-ynqdc?file=/example.js

Answer (score 0):

The route exact path is matching strictly and not allowing the /one and /two. Changing the exact path to /* permits it.
We can remove path and url variables in the address.
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dew-3xvgm?file=/example.js

Comment: I see, so that fixes the initial issue of the routing, there is still the question of how do I route to the `HigherLevelComponent`? In the changes you made, when you navigate to `base/path/higher_level_route`, you'll see that the component is not being rendered, even though it matches the path

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems here.

1 - As already explained, remove `exact` prop as it prevents the rendering of CoreComponent.

2 - change path `${path}/one` to `${path}one` in all the `Route` in CoreComponent.
You can log both `path` and `url` to see what value actually it holds.
In your current situation, the value of path is `//one` and the value of link is `/one`. 
So removing a slash makes everything work as expected.

3 - You need to change the order of route in the `RoutingApp` component. Since `Switch` always render only one route(i.e the 1st match), you need to place `/higher_level_route` first and then the `'/'`.

```
<Router basename="/base/path">
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/higher_level_route">
       <HigherLevelComponent />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
       <CoreComponent />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

I hope it helps now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There's still the issue which I posted in @visnu's post above regarding the routing from the child to the different parent route `higher_level_route` not rendering the `HigherLevelComponent`, if you have any idea why?

Comment: When removing the `exact` prop, it seems that the `higher_level_route` is never being reached, I believe that's why I Initially used exact

Comment: I have edited the answer, i hope now it is clear. :)